# Is there a way to include environment variables in Quip Live Apps?

Tags: liveapps

Is there a way to include environment variables in Quip Live Apps?

I am planning to include a third-party plugin in my live app and need some .env file for the app to pick values ad hoc. Is there any way??

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay!

I'm afraid Quip Live Apps don't support environment variables, however you can use window.localStorage yourself and pick up variables from there if required.

Hope this helps!